# contributing to ros

Tags: ros, library

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I wrote a new package for ros groovy ([here](https://github.com/vonovak/text_locator)) and I would like to share it with others so that they can use just apt-get to install it. However, I have some questions before I do so:

1. there is a static library that the node needs to run. What should my CMakeLists.txt look like so that the library gets installed when somebody uses apt-get install?
2. This is more of a linux question:
   I read the page about contributing to ros - so I know I only share my repo. But the repo does not contain the executables. From what I have read [online](http://nixcraft.com/ubuntu-debian/14489-how-does-apt-get-install-work.html) it seems that apt-get install does not involve any compiling - by using apt-get we are downloading executables right away. So where are they stored and how do they come to life?

thanks for anwerring

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/75316/contributing-to-ros/) by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-08-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Usually packages are built with shared libraries when being installed onto a system.  I recommend you do some reading on CMake Tutorials in general.

To contribute code back to the community there's a Contributing link on the home page [www.ros.org](http://www.ros.org)

And from that you specifically want to look at http://ros.org/wiki/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation for releasing.

2. The released source is built into binary debian packages on a buildfarm and then stored in apt repositories.  The web interface for the buildfarm is at http://jenkins.ros.org and the packages are hosted at http://packages.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vonovak](https://answers.ros.org/users/4872/vonovak/) on 2013-08-28**:
I still don't quite understand the answer to 1. My node needs an external library that I have downloaded and compiled and put it in the lib directory of the package. It is also in the repo. Will it get installed when I do all the steps in the page you linked?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-29**:
If you downloaded and compiled that I'd recommend to provide the sources and include them in the build instead of a pre-compiled library. For binaries you'd need to provide builds for every system that will be supported.